# Swift - Pulling a link from init parameters to MapView annotation

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am working on a practice app to learn swift which places pins on a map and has a clickable link to each pin's corresponding website via the detail disclosure. I am able to pull the coordinates as well as the title and subtitle for each pin from an init but am struggling on pulling the "site" from each corresponding location.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class TruckAnnotation:NSObject,MKAnnotation{
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?
    var site: String?
    init(_ latitude:CLLocationDegrees,_ longitude:CLLocationDegrees,title:String,subtitle:String,site:String){
        self.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.site = site
    }
}
 
 
class TruckAnnotations: NSObject {
    var trucks:[TruckAnnotation]
    
    override init(){
        trucks = [TruckAnnotation(41.6614,-72.6076, title: "Truck 1", subtitle:"Brewery 1", site: "https://www.google.com")]
        trucks += [TruckAnnotation(41.7617,-72.5776, title: "Truck 2", subtitle:"Brewery 2", site: "https://www.google.com")]
        trucks += [TruckAnnotation(41.6580,-72.6524, title: "Truck 3", subtitle:"Brewery 3", site: "https://www.google.com")]
        trucks += [TruckAnnotation(41.5875,-72.5823, title: "Truck 4", subtitle:"Park 1", site: "https://www.google.com")]
         trucks += [TruckAnnotation(41.6747,-72.5476, title: "Truck 5", subtitle:"Brewery 4", site: "https://www.google.com")]
         trucks += [TruckAnnotation(41.6699,-72.7568 , title: "Truck 6", subtitle:"Vineyard 1", site: "https://www.google.com")]
         trucks += [TruckAnnotation(41.7421,-72.6312 , title: "Truck 7", subtitle:"Brewery 5", site: "https://www.google.com")]
         trucks += [TruckAnnotation(41.6312,-72.5846, title: "Truck 8", subtitle:"Vineyard 2", site: "https://www.google.com")]
         trucks += [TruckAnnotation(41.8202,-72.5100, title: "Truck 9", subtitle:"Park 2", site: "https://www.google.com")]
    }
}
```

Below is how I am using the annotations in the mapkit.

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    var annotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView()
    guard let annotation = annotation as? TruckAnnotation else {return nil}
    let identifier = ""
    if let dequedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(
        withIdentifier: identifier)
        as? MKMarkerAnnotationView {
        annotationView = dequedView
    } else{
        annotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
    }
    annotationView.canShowCallout = true
    annotationView.calloutOffset  = CGPoint(x: 0, y:5)
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure) as UIButton
    annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure) as UIButton
    annotationView.clusteringIdentifier = identifier
    return annotationView
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    
    let buttonPressed = annotationView.annotation!.title!
    let buttonPressedMid =
    
        if control == annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
        print("Right Disclosure Pressed!")
        print("\(String(describing: annotationView.annotation!.title!))")
        print("https://www.\(String(describing: buttonPressed)).com")
        print("site link")
        if let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com"){
            UIApplication.shared.open(url as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)            }
    }
    if control == annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView {
        print("Left Disclosure Pressed!")
        if let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.yahoo.com"){
           UIApplication.shared.open(url as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)            }
    }
}
```

Obviously Google.com/Yahoo.com are placeholders and I am trying to pull unique values from each collection.

(If you can't tell, I am very much a beginner, so please bear with me. This is a learning exercise to become more familiar with ios development).

Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't it better if you just let the user tap a button to access the given URL?

Comment: @Rob That's it. I forgot to use guard to "pull in" the TruckAnnotation properties.

Answer (score 1):

Often, in `calloutAccessoryControlTapped`, we would cast to our custom annotation:

```
guard let annotation = annotationView.annotation as? TruckAnnotation else { return }
```

Then we can retrieve the custom properties (of the `TruckAnnotation` in this case) to determine the correct course of action.